# param is missing or the value is empty hidden_field_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am having problem sending values to my controller via a `form_tag`-- It looks like the params are missing, I get this error: `ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: story`

```
<% @locations.each do |post| %>
          <div class="box col3">
             <img src="<%= post[:image] %>">
         <small>username: </small><%= post[:username]%>
         <small>posted date: </small><%= post[:created_time] %>
         <small>place: </small><%= post[:place] %>
         <small>tags: </small> <%= post[:hash_tags] %>
         <small>lat: </small> <%= post[:lat] %>
         <small>lg: </small> <%= post[:lg] %>
         <div class="like-button">
            <%= form_tag('/stories/create', remote: true) do  %>
              <%= hidden_field_tag 'avatar', "#{post[:image]}" %>
              <%= hidden_field_tag 'description', "#{post[:username]}" %>
              <%= submit_tag "Like", class: "btn btn-warning like-button" %>
            <% end %>
         </div>
          </div>
<%end%>
```

`@locations` is an array of hashes.

for example `@locations.first` yield:

```
{:lat=>40.7519798,
 :lg=>-73.9475174,
 :place=>"Z Hotel NY",
 :profile_picture=>
  "http://photos-g.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-xtp1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/12105211_896812917070398_1478405438_a.jpg",
 :hash_tags=>[],
 :username=>"dannessex90",
 :fullname=>"Dann Essex",
 :created_time=>"2015-11-02 22:41:25 -0500",
 :image=>
  "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/11421986_972505559476106_241708523_n.jpg"}
```

`story controller`:

```
class StoriesController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @stories = Story.all
    end

    def show

    end

    def new
        @story = Story.new
    end

    def edit

    end

    def create
        current_location = request.remote_ip
        binding.pry
        coordinates = Location.get_coord(story_params[:location])
        params = {description: story_params[:description], location: story_params[:location], latitude: coordinates[0], longitude: coordinates[1], avatar: story_params[:avatar]}
        @story = current_user.stories.build(params)
        if @story.save

            redirect_to url_for(:controller => :users, :action => :my_stories)
        else
            render 'searches/result'
        end
    end

    private

    def story_params
        params.require(:story).permit(:description, :location, :avatar, :tag_list)

    end
end
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: It's expecting a `:story ` param but you are not submitting it. Add: `<small>story: </small> <%= post[:story] %>` to the list. See if that fixes your problem.

Comment: In your controller, add something like `puts params.inspect` and see what you're getting back (it'll show up in the rails console window). Then you can see how the actual params you're getting differ from what you expect to see. Often these things are due to an extra layer.

Comment: Side-note: your strings are already stringy enough... you don't need to put them inside of another string to make them more stringy eg: `"#{post[:username]}"` can just be `post[:username]`

Comment: Please show your corresponding controller code

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam that would just give me `nil` since post doesn't have an key of  `:story`

Comment: I misunderstood it in the beginning. Please show us your controller code. And, also, the output of: `puts params.inspect` inside your controller's action.

Comment: I suspect that, somehow you have `:story` in your strong param definition and that's why it's giving you that message. I can confirm when you show your controller code.

Comment: updated. `params.inspect` just gives me `nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you have specified to require `story` in your parameters through `strong_params` i.e. in your `story_params` method.

The view side is not passing the parameters nested under `story` param. That's why you are getting this error.

To solve this issue, you can change your `story_params` method to this (without the `require(:story)` part, because you are not using it in your controller):

```
def story_params
   params.permit(:description, :location, :avatar, :tag_list)
end
```